# Redesign of the tags page is hard to read with our tag styling

Tags: discussion, tagging, design

All the extra information on the tags page seems like a good idea and the page looks fine on, say, StackOverflow, where the tags still jump out because of their background and bounding box, but our tags are nearly the same font/size/weight as the rest of the text on that page and have no bounding box, so the tags do not stand out.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing around with the styles, I think it would be sufficient to up the `font-size` from `13px` to `14px` and add `font-weight:bold` on the element/class `a.post-tag` on that page.

Comment: I'll look into this (you may note another difference on math and cstheory relative to other tag pages in the network with indentation of tags). We also need help populating the first page of tag excerpts if you have time. I'm not so concerned about page 2 and deeper, but I feel page 1 is critical to understanding how tags work both for experienced users and new users.